# You don't have permission to access /project on this server

Tags: macos, apache, permissions

I have this problem: "You don't have permission to access /project on this server."
And, what makes me feel trouble is that, here in terminal:

```
sol@Sol-MacMini /Library/WebServer/Documents>sudo ln -s /User/sol/Documents/project/ ./project
sol@Sol-MacMini /Library/WebServer/Documents>sudo ln -s /Applications/web/ci/ ./ci
sol@Sol-MacMini /Library/WebServer/Documents>ls
CodeIgniter         ci
PoweredByMacOSX.gif     m-plan
PoweredByMacOSXLarge.gif    project
```

But in my browser,I can't see the "project" when input "localhost". If input "localhost/ci",it works and it does not work when "localhost/project". I thought it maybe has something wrong with my apache setting.

What can I do to solve this?

Some more clarification:

I have created a symbolic link "project" under apache's htdocs directory, which points to a "project" directory under my home. The permission of both the symbolic link and the directory should be fine, as shown below:

/Library/WebServer/Documents>ls -l

lrwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 35 12 21 17:59 project -> /Users/sol/Documents/htdocs/project

sol@Sol-MacMini ~/Documents/htdocs>ls -l

drwxr-xr-x@ 15 sol admin 510 12 21 17:59 project

As you can see, it is quite weird that I get "Permission denied" error given the above file permissions set.

Answer (score 0):

highlight the project folder in the apache directory. Press command + i and make sure in permissions that everyone can read.

Comment: some clarification:
I have created a symbolic link "project" under apache's htdocs directory, which points to a "project" directory under my home. The permission of both the symbolic link and the directory should be fine, as shown below:
/Library/WebServer/Documents>ls -l
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     35 12 21 17:59 project -> /Users/sol/Documents/htdocs/project

sol@Sol-MacMini ~/Documents/htdocs>ls -l
drwxr-xr-x@ 15 sol  admin   510 12 21 17:59 project

As you can see, it is quite weird that I get "Permission denied" error given the above file permissions set.